# Swift gzipped response

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gzip

I've serialized a JSON response in my Swift app  and the parsed result is a single byte array

```
{
d =     (
    31,
    139,
    8,
    0,
    0,
    9,
    110,
    136,
    0,
    255,
    236,
    125,
```

how do I decode this byte array into actual data i can work with?

here is my swift code that fetches and parses the response

`func getWRHPSData(completionHandlerForPOST: @escaping (_ result: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) -> Void {

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: createURL())
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("gzip, inflate", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        func sendError(_ error: String) {
            print(error)
            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : error]
            completionHandlerForPOST(nil, NSError(domain: "taskForGETMethod", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there an error? */
        guard (error == nil) else {
            sendError("There was an error with your request: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        /* GUARD: Did we get a successful 2XX response? */
        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {
            sendError("Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!")
            return
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there any data returned? */
        guard let data = data else {
            sendError("No data was returned by the request!")
            return
        }



        /* 5/6. Parse the data and use the data (happens in completion handler) */
        self.parseData(data, completionHandlerForConvertData: completionHandlerForPOST)
    }

    /* 7. Start the request */
    task.resume()
}

// given raw JSON, return a usable Foundation object
private func parseData(_ data: Data, completionHandlerForConvertData: (_ result: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    var parsedResult: AnyObject! = nil
    do {
        parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
    } catch {
        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'"]
        completionHandlerForConvertData(nil, NSError(domain: "convertDataWithCompletionHandler", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
    }

    print(parsedResult)
    completionHandlerForConvertData(parsedResult, nil)
}`
```

Comment: This question needs more information.  What I see up there looks like a Dictionary with a value that's an array object.  And what do you want the result to be?  JSON or Gzipped or both?  What does your code look like so far?

Comment: I need to decode this byte array that is delivered in the response data, I tried Gzip to gunzip it but it errors, im not familiar with Gzipped responses and how to work with them in swift